# Trip last 7 digits php

Tags: php, text, trim

I need to trim the last 7 digits in one field of my form

and I need to trim the first three digits in another form

Im assuming that I use ltrim and rtrim but how exactly do I write it? I think i need to use ltrim and rtrim but I don't know how to write the code

Comment: [`substr`](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: substr worked great thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and rtrim() will remove the spacing characters.

Slapyo is correct, [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is probably a way of doing it. It may look something like:

```
<?php

$Var = "mystringofcharacters";
$Result = substr($Var,0,strlen($Var)-7);

echo $Result;
?>
```

Should return: mystringofcha

We use strlen() because of how you want to return the string, "all characters except the last X" means you need to know how long it is, then get all the other characters.

If you wanted only the last 7 characters, you'd replace the strlen($Var)-7 section with just -7.